# ffmpeg infinite loop over multiple images to v4l2

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to display two images that alternate (3sec each) in infinite loop into v4l2 virtual camera.

i tried this command:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -f concat -safe 0 -r 1 -i input.txt -vf format=yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

with content of **input.txt**

```
file '1.png'
file '1.png'
file '1.png'
file '2.png'
file '2.png'
file '2.png'
```

but unfortunately it didn't work, i can see only first image when i display the virtual camera in the browser.

the issue is that the same command using a video file output, works fine!

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -f concat -safe 0 -r 1 -i input.txt -vf format=yuv420p output.mp4 -y
```

and i want to avoid creating mp4 file for each combination of images that i want to stream out